# What's inside this fishing reel?

Tags: fishing, fishing-rods

I saw a teardown of a reel and noticed a part inside the spool:

[image]

https://youtu.be/_NKVN9fRD4k?t=327

Does anyone know what the spring does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metal tab is called the click tongue, and the spring holds the click tongue against a sprocket on the reel spindle. Together they are responsible for the clicking sound a reel makes when line is pulled off against the drag, for example, when fighting a large fish. If a fish removes line rapidly, the individual clicks sound more like a continuous whine, a coveted sound to anglers known as a screaming drag.

There are other mechanisms in use in some reels, but I've seen this on Penn reels before. This [image search link](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=penn%20reel%20click%20tongue&iax=images&ia=images) shows a number of variations.